# Connection pooling for external connections in Airflow

Tags: python, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I am trying to find a way for connection pool management for external connections created in Airflow.
Airflow version : 2.1.0
Python Version : 3.9.5
Airflow DB : SQLite
External connections created :  MySQL and Snowflake

I know there are properties in airflow.cfg file

```
sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True  
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
```

But these properties are for managing the airflow internal DB which is SQLite in my case.

I have few tasks which are reading or writing data in MySQL and Snowflake.

```
snowflake_insert = SnowflakeOperator(
          task_id='insert_snowflake',
          dag=dag,
          snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
          sql="Some Insert query",
          warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
          database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
          schema=SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA,
          role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE
     )
```

and

```
insert_mysql_task = MySqlOperator(task_id='insert_record', mysql_conn_id='mysql_default', sql="some insert query", dag=dag)
```

Reading data from MySQL

```
def get_records():
    mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id="mysql_default")
    records = mysql_hook.get_records(sql=r"""Some select query""")
    print(records)
```

What I observed is a new session is getting created for each of the task (there are multiple tasks in the same dag) for Snowflake, haven't verified the same for MySQL.

Is there a way to maintain connection pool for external connections (in my case Snowflake and MySQL) or any other way to run all the queries in same DAG in same session ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow offers using [Pools](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html#pools) as a way to limit concurrency to an external service.

You can create a Pool via the UI:
Menu -> Admin -> Pools

Or with [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#set) :

```
airflow pools set NAME slots
```

The pool has slots which define how many tasks that use the resources can run in parallel. If the pool is full the tasks will queued untill a slot is opened.

To use the pool in operators is simply adding `pool=Name` to the Operator.

In your case assuming `Pool` was created with the name snowflake then:

```
snowflake_insert = SnowflakeOperator(
          task_id='insert_snowflake',
          dag=dag,
          snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID,
          sql="Some Insert query",
          warehouse=SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE,
          database=SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE,
          schema=SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA,
          role=SNOWFLAKE_ROLE,
          pool='snowflake',
     )
```

Note that by default a task occupy 1 slot in the pool but this is configurable. A task may occupy more than 1 slot if using `pool_slots` example:

```
snowflake_insert = SnowflakeOperator(
          task_id='insert_snowflake',
          ...
          pool='snowflake',
          pool_slots=2,
     )
```

Comment: Hi @Elad thanks for the quick reply.
I guess the pool which you mentioned is for task pool management.
I want something for database connection pool management. 
Will this pool parameter work for database connections also ? Thanks

Comment: You choose what to do with this pool. For example you can choose that a specific pool must be used when accessing a specific connection. You can use cluster policy https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/cluster-policies.html to create all kinds of encorments

Comment: @Elad Could you please explain where a DB pool instance is stored in this case? Could we create e.g. cx_oracle SessionPool instance somewhere and share it between tasks?